# TikZ: drawing an arrow using nodes at specific text positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, tikz-arrows

I have two `enumerate` environments and I want to draw some arrows from some items of one `enumerate` environment to the other. So I thought I could use the `tikz` package for that, defines some `node`s and draw lines between them.

I can, of course, do this in the stupid way, as in my example, by manually setting the positions of the nodes in an annoying trial and error procedure. Is there another, more intelligent method, to define a node, for example, at a given text position, in this case at each of the items and then referencing and using them later? Also, how do I get lines that are connected?

```
\documentclass{report}

% used for easy formatting changes of enumerate-lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

% for enabling the TikZ magic
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item car1
\item car2
\item car3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item door
\item engine
\item window
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
% nodes
\node (A) at (-0.5, 2.3) {};
\node (B) at (-1.5, 2.3) {};
\node (C) at (-1.5, 3.8) {};
\node (D) at (-0.5, 3.8) {};
\node (1) at (3, 0) {};
% arrows
\draw[->] 
    (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows (note that I actually want a connected line...):

[image]

Comment: Clearly, using `tikzmark` library would save you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tikzmark` library is a very nice asset to do this. Be sure to compile at least twice.

[image: drawing an arrow using nodes at specific text positions]

```
\documentclass{report}

% used for easy formatting changes of enumerate-lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

% for enabling the TikZ magic
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item car1
    \item \tikzmark{A} car2
    \item car3
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item \tikzmark{B} door
        \item engine
        \item window
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[->] ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=1mm]pic cs:B) --++ (-1,0) |- ([xshift=-8mm,yshift=1mm]pic cs:A);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had no idea about `tikzmark`, what a powerful package, thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed! Glad you discovered it. And thanks to Andrew Stacey, a fellow member of TeX-SE.

Answer (score 3):

tkz-linknodes is an old package, currently considered obsolete. You need to compile twice.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem,tkz-linknodes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{NodesList}[margin=10cm]
\begin{enumerate}
\item car1\AddNode%
\item car2
\item car3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item door
\item engine \AddNode%
\item window
\end{enumerate}

{\tikzset{ArrowStyle/.append style = {->,red,  rounded corners}}
\LinkNodes{}}
\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand the documentation from [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes) correctly, this package is from 2011 - still good to know that there might be an alternative to the accepted answer

Comment: @Alf tizkmark is also old 2009 I think ... The principle is the same you place two nodes on a page and by using overlay,remember picture you can link these two nodes. It's quite easy even without the packages. I created tkz-linknodes mainly to create links between lines of mathematical equations.

Comment: thanks for the clarification